# What did the mung bean become?

Tags: knowledge, situation

> Mung bean fell from a tall building. Mung bean fell to the ground,
> what did the mung bean become?

Tips:

> ***Mung bean fell from a tall building.***

What did the mung bean become?

Answer (score 2):

The mung bean may have become

> maash, which is another word for [mung bean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mung_bean) and also sounds like 'mash', which something might become after falling from a tall building.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sorry this answer is wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is a very weird answer based on a loophole, but I think the mung bean became

> A part of this riddle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sorry this answer is wrong

Comment: @MyCar I knew it was probably not the answer you were looking for, but it is technically correct. I'll keep thinking.

Comment: @MyCar Sorry, but no. There could only be a few possible options.

Comment: Cheese Cake I edited.

Comment: Hope someone has the right answer to this and that question :)